# Get Email Id of device which is configured with PlayStore

Tags: android, gmail, google-play-services

Is it possible to get email id/ ids which are configured with PlayStore app in android device.

```
Pattern emailPattern = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS; 
                Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(getActivity()).getAccounts();
                for (Account account : accounts) {
                    if (emailPattern.matcher(account.name).matches()) {
                        primaryEmailID = account.name;

                    }
                }
```

By using this code I get all sets of email ids configured in device i.e, gmail, yahoo, etc.
But how can I get email ids of only gmail account(I guess email ids in gmail account gets configured in playstore).

Comment: What if you use `AccountManager.get(getActivity()).getAccountsByType("com.google")`?

Comment: Cool. I posted it as an answer, accept it if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access just to Google accounts try using:

```
AccountManager.get(getActivity()).getAccountsByType("com.google")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public String getMailId() {
    String strGmail = null;
    try {
        Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(this).getAccounts();
        Log.e("PIKLOG", "Size: " + accounts.length);
        for (Account account : accounts) {

            String possibleEmail = account.name;
            String type = account.type;

            if (type.equals("com.google")) {

                strGmail = possibleEmail;
                Log.e("PIKLOG", "Emails: " + strGmail);
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return strGmail;
}
```

Comment: Add some description also

Answer (score 0):

```
Account[] accounts=AccountManager.getAccountsByType(GoogleAuthUtil.GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE);
```