# How to get the account that was used to download the app?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, verification, developer-payload

### Background

I wish to get the account details of the user (just the email) that was used in order to download the app from the play store.

The reason is very simple: In-App-Billing allows to add something that is called "developer payload" (described on [**this google IO lecture**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=DgcJPIRpfSk#t=1407)) to purchases, so that it will verify that the purchase is legit, because it has a tag that identifies the purchase with the current user.

I think other people can think of other reasons to get it. maybe for saving games progress , for example.

### The problem

Currently, All I know that you can do is to get ALL of the accounts (using the [**AccountManager**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) as shown [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2175688/878126)) .

However, I'm not sure if that's the best thing to do.

### The question

How do I achieve such a thing?

Also, is getting the list of all of the accounts also a good thing for this purpose (in app billing verification) ? Is it even a good thing to put the account info into the developer-payload of the purchase?

Comment: check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16958535/get-email-id-of-device-which-is-configured-with-playstore I haven't tried yet but it seems helpful to you. you can also use random string as a developer payload check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17196562/token-that-identify-the-user/17205999#17205999

Comment: well as i've said i already know how to get all of the accounts. i want to know which one was used to download the current app. about the random strings , how would you recover them when the user has installed the app on another device (or uninstalled&re-installed it) ?  using the backupManager ?

Comment: I think that it's possible to store and restore the developer-payload by using SharedPreferencesBackupHelper : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/backup/SharedPreferencesBackupHelper.html , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161530/android-sharedpreferences-backup-not-working

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper, have you solved your problem? Please share the solution. Thanks

Comment: @sberezin Not using the method I wanted. Instead, I've put all of the accounts data into the mix, and when needed to verify, I've checked this data vs all the accounts the user currently have. However, maybe I can assume that the first account is always the one that was used for downloading the app.

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper, thanks. But now Google Play allows to choose an account before downloading and when you do in-app purchase it uses the same one. But you can't see it from within the app (at least it seems so)...

Comment: @sberezin I see. That's probably why I asked this question. So use what I did instead.